# CORS Filter Missing Angular

Tags: angularjs

From my Angular client, i am invoking another application URL which will return a JSON object.

When i try in IE11 , it works fine but in Firefox and Chrome, i get:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

I tried to add the Access-Control-Allow-origin in the header, i started get CORS Request Failed.

How can i handle this scenario in my angular 1.5 application?

Comment: *"I tried to add the Access-Control-Allow-origin in the header"* then you need to do more research on what CORS is and where the headers belong. The request is likely failing in firefox and chrome because they are ***properly*** sending a preflight, and the api is ***improperly*** responding to it.

Answer (score 2):

### Access-Control-Allow-origin

First of all it has **nothing to do with angular**. You make an request to backend and your backend response to the request. 
***CORS Filter Missing Angular*** there is no CORS Filter Missing Angular in angular but in your api.  You need to set CORS Filter in your api so your angular application can make a request and api can response to that.

### This picture describe how cors filter works

[image]